# Compile-time OK, run-time error while using class from namespace in typescript with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, swagger-codegen

I use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) with the `-l typescript-angular` option to generate a library of REST consumer services. The generated code looks like this (`DefaultApi.ts`):

```
namespace API.Client {
    'use strict';

    export class DefaultApi {
        protected basePath = 'http://localhost:7331/v1';
        public defaultHeaders : any = {};

        static $inject: string[] = ['$http', '$httpParamSerializer', 'basePath'];

        constructor(protected $http: ng.IHttpService, protected $httpParamSerializer?: (d: any) => any, basePath?: string) {
            if (basePath !== undefined) {
                this.basePath = basePath;
            }
        }

        private extendObj<T1,T2>(objA: T1, objB: T2) {
            for(let key in objB){
                if(objB.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    objA[key] = objB[key];
                }
            }
            return <T1&T2>objA;
        }

        /**
         * Delete a person.
         * Deletes a specified individual and all of that person&#39;s connections. 
         * @param id The id of the person to delete
         */
        public deletePersonById (id: number, extraHttpRequestParams?: any ) : ng.IHttpPromise<{}> {/*...*/}

        /* etc... */
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are concrete classes that need to be used but are declared inside of a namespace, i.e. not `import`able. My editor (VSCode) doesn't complain when I reference `API.Client.DefaultApi` despite the lack of an `import` because it picks up the definition as part of a declared namespace I suppose. But at run-time the browser complains that `API` is not defined.

I am using webpack to bundle my code. I see a few other questions on SO that are kind of like this one, but had no luck with the answers there.

EDIT:

As requested, here are my configuration files for ts and webpack:

webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'tslint'
      }
    ],

    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|less)$/,
        loaders: [
          'style',
          'css',
          'less',
          'postcss'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate',
          'ts'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    })
  ],
  postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/app'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: [
      '',
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.ts'
    ]
  },
  entry: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`,
  ts: {
    configFileName: '../tsconfig.json'
  },
  tslint: {
    configuration: require('../tslint.json')
  }
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src/app",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "!typings/**",
    "!node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you share your webpack config and tsconfig ?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran added. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: It seems to me that you use typescript 2.x. What you think about Salsa & webpack resolve.alias solution describe below?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to fix this, an ease and another complex:

1. change generated ts file.

Add the following code at the end of generated code:

```
export = API.Client;
```

Now, you can use `import` in your modules without problems, eg:

```
import {DefaultApi} from './generated-code';
```

2. But if change generated file is not an option, appeal to the [Salsa compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Salsa)!

**The idea:**

*Split the modular code and not modular code with differents tsconfig. Mix modular code and not modular with Salsa, webpack resolve alias and javascript support.*

Tutorial:

> *TL;DR*  Here a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AbraaoAlves/Salsa-for-rescue) applying this solution.

1. Create a new tsconfig.generate.json to generated code handle , just generatred code, eg:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "outFile": "module-generated-code.js"
   },
   "files": ["generated-code.ts"]
}
```

2. in your initial tsconfig.json, you must exclude generated ts files. This will ensure that there is no unnecessary code, eg:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {

   },
   "exclude": ["generated-code.ts"]
}
```

3. Now, the ace in the hole!You will add a `api.js` file and reference it in your `tsconfig.generate.json`. Yes, it is a js file, it is here that Salsa gets into action. And to do this you must enable `allowJs` feature in tsconfig

```
{ 
   "compilerOptions": {
      "outFile": "module-generate-code.js", "allowJs": true
   },
   "files": ["generated-code.ts", "api.js"]
}
```

These files are basically to export via commonjs your generated code without touch it.

```
/// <reference path="./namespacing-code.ts" />
// typescript compiler don't warning this because is Salsa!
module.exports = API.Client;
```

Now, note in  `tsconfig.generate.json` and your `outFile` property. If you test the compiler (`tsc -p tsconfig.generate.json`), you see all your generated files concatenated in `module-generate-code.js`, and the last line must be like  in this:

`module.exports = API.Client;`

Nearly Done!

Now, you can use the `module-generate-code.js` in your own code with `import`! But how js files do not have the best definitions, then you have config a resolve.alias in webpack.config and tsconfig.json

```
{ //webpack.config
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js'],
      alias:{ 'api':'./module-generated-code.js'
    }
}
```

```
{ //tsconfig.json
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true, //remember of enabling Salsa here too
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "api":["api.js"] //it is just get type definitions from generated files
        }
     },
```

Now you can use your generate code without touch it: `import api from 'api';`

Any doubt, here a [GitHub](https://github.com/AbraaoAlves/Salsa-for-rescue) repo using this approach.
I hope I´ve helped

Answer (score 0):

The current version of swagger-codegen TypeScript Angular generator does not wrap the DefaultApi in a namespace.

Update and regenerate. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hmm... I just checked and I am using version 2.2.1, which appears to be the latest release (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases).

Comment: Ok. I was wrong. I see now this is for the angular 1.x typescript generator, not the angular 2. I would suggest opening an issue with the swagger-codegen team, suggest a command line option to suppress adding a namespace

Comment: Honest mistake. Appreciate you looking into it.